# Accessing Source Url in Clipboard with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

My Goal is to get Access of the Source Url of the Original Context of the Data copied to the Clipboard.
The Goal is to Implement the Behavior like in OneNote too Apend that Link to the Text Pasted.
Currently my Goal is to add the functionality via Plugin to Obsidian via JS.

A Code Example how it is done in OneNote can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140721-00/?p=453).

The Format which is used is specified as CF_Html.
The Documentation that Mentioned the Source Url Variable is found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767917(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

I know it is a in the Hand of the App that adds the Information to the Clipboard.
And its most likely Windows/ & Implementation Specific.

In the Documentation [now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format) the Mention of the Source URL property is gone.

When I try to paste it in OneNote, the Functionality is still there.
[image: OneNote Pasted from Feature]
When trying to Retrieve the Clipboard in JavaScript via the Clipboard API mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read).

```
export async function myBlobTransform(input) {
  if (!input.types.includes("text/html")) {
      return { kind: "err", value: "No html found in clipboard!" };
  }
  const html = await input.getType("text/html");
  return html.text();
}
myBlobTransform.type = "blob";
```

It just prints out the Html Version of the Copied Text.
Alternative text/plain is available which, gives me the Text Unformated.
The Information which im looking for is not Available.

After looking for what Mime Types should be available. [See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

I thought that `application/octet-stream` could be a Solution.
Its not Available, even as its mentioned as Default type.

How can i access the Information of the Source Url in Javascript?
What would be your suggested Solution/Workaround to this problem to implement the Feature like in One Note in JavaScript/Obsidian?

Comment: I don't think what you are looking for, actually exists - the clipboard content does not have any "from" properties. What OneNote is doing there in your screenshot, appears to be the same principle as explained under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text - the extra text (current URL) gets added the moment the content gets copied _into_ the clipboard.

Comment: So if your scenario is that you have access to the source where this gets copied _from_, you could implement that technique. If your scenario is that you are only at the _receiving_ end, you get pasted content that was copied from somewhere "outside" - I don't think what you want is possible.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your Time.
Your Mention would be an Option with a Plugin for Chrome to just Append it to the Clipboard. Saddly no such Plugin as far as i looked exists yet.

If your Theorie is correct it would mean the Source URL is Website Specific added via JavaScript when i understand it correctly.
This would mean that it would appear as a hidden Div in the plain Html code.
I just tried with your Comment. It doesn't Appear in the src with my Example code.
When I copy it to OneNote however it, still appends the Link somehow.
Even more, i never noticed it not working on any Website.

Comment: @CBroe an Example how it looks can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141630/how-can-i-read-raw-cf-html-clipboard-data-in-a-webpage-or-c

And as Mentioned in the Documentation and as Mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843792/why-microsoft-onenote-can-show-a-link-to-the-contents-are-copied-from

It seems too atleast have Existed.
And it still Works in OneNote so the Functionality Still seems to be there

Comment: Are you talking about something you copied from within OneNote to begin with, or are you talking about something you copied from just _any_ arbitrary website, and then pasted into OneNote? If it is the latter, then presumably the info about the "origin" of the copied content must be stored in the clipboard _somewhere_. But I don't know what OneNote actually uses to access the clipboard content, guess you'd have to find that in the source somewhere then to check ...

Comment: Maybe OneNote picks a different clipboard data format? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70543117/1427878 - I'd try one of the tools mentioned there to see what the clipboard actually contains, and if you find the URL info in any of those formats.

Comment: Im talking about "about something you copied from just any arbitrary website, and then past[ing it] into OneNote".

The Origin is Stored in Windows the Documentation for it, as mentioned in the Example is found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767917(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
An Example on how to retrieve it in another Language ( C#) is found here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140721-00/?p=453
In my Understanding the Limitation is in the Clipboard Api which doesnt Provide this  deep Access.

Comment: as far as I understand, those informations are actually stored inside the Clipboard at the OS level.. so OneNote can easily retrieve those metadata but they are not made available by the Clipboard API inside the browser. So you have no chance to get the same information that OneNote has, with code running inside a browser. All you can as already suggested, is writing your own browser addon that will listen for the copy event on any page and will add the window.location.href to the copied content so that it will be pasted as is

Comment: @DiegoD is there a possible Solution to replace the Clipboard API with something that allows this deep of OS Access?

Your Idea is Probably the more Universal one, as it's a Solution could satisfy more Use Cases.

Comment: I thought you were talking about using a web version of OneNote here to begin with, but apparently - not?

Comment: I checked myself and that feature isn't available on the web version... at least not that I know of; while on the desktop version it just pastes the content including the source url. This brings credit to the hypotesis of the Clipboard API obscuring those information. The latest suggestion CBroe gave before shed lots of light on the whole point targeting everything in one place. The Windows API stores a map where at any given time there are multiple contents for each copied _item_. Each one mapped to a _type_. The content is of type _CF_HTML_ and if you try from browser it just returns empty

Comment: @CBroe sorry for the misunderstanding.
No I meant the Desktop Version. 
Didn't know of the Web Version, but as tested by Diego D (Thanks), it is not Possible there.